# how can I create a function that reads words in words.txt(thinkpython2) and put them as keys in a dict where values are len(word)

Tags: python, function, dictionary

I'm  absolute beginner. My solution doesn't work. I can't understand why.

```
fin=open('words.txt')
fin.readline()

for line in fin:
    word=line.strip()

def diz():
    d={} 
    for word in line:
        d[word]=len(word)           
    return d

diz()
print(diz())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is very nearly working, with a few key mistakes. The first is the `readline` call; you didn't use its return value, so all it did was skip the first word in the word list. Second is how you pass a word from the `for line in fin` loop into `diz`; there's only the one variable `line`, and it will simply hold the last word in the word list by the time `diz` is called. Thirdly, `line` isn't a list of words but a string holding one line (and typically word lists have one word per line). Thus `for word in line` produces all the letters in that last line, not words.

We can clean this up by moving things a little:

```
fin=open('words.txt')

d={} 
for line in fin:
    word=line.strip()
    d[word]=len(word)           
print(d)
```

We could make this more concise or generic, but this keeps the crucial steps from your code.

Answer (score 0):

The most pythonic way to do this is to first read the words like so:

```
d = {}
with open('words.txt', 'r') as fin:
    raw_words = fin.readlines()

for raw_word in raw_words:
    word = raw_word.strip()
    d[word] = len(word)

# should print the desired dict
print(d)
```

The "with" block takes care of the close for you while the for inserts to the dict the words with their length.

Comment: Some might call it overcomplicated. You can do `d = {word: len(word) for word in open('words.txt').read().split()}`, skipping the parts about holding a file object that may or may not be closed, not caring if the words are split by lines or spaces, or storing an incomplete dictionary in a name.

Comment: what you suggests is a bad habit to write code because you do not close your handler which can create problems in the future. It is best to write an extra line and not be bother with future problems

Comment: Yet I'd not assume that's a critical issue for the Python beginner. Learning of context managers is good, but the problems you refer to occur after you have left hundreds of unneeded open files around - not a single one, already passed to the garbage collection. It does get important if you're writing.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a [dictionary comprehension](https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/python-dictionary-comprehension):

Sample file (words.txt):

```
python
eggs
foo
bar 
monthy
```

Code:

```
with open('words.txt', 'r') as fwrd:
    words = fwrd.readlines()

diz = {wrd.strip(): len(wrd) for wrd in words}
print(diz)
```

Output:

```
{'python': 7, 'eggs': 5, 'foo': 4, 'bar': 4, 'monthy': 6}
```